# Symfony 2: protect login page and administrator with ip

Tags: php, security, symfony

I would like to protect my administrator folder like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/administrator/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: myip }
    - { path: ^/administrator, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ip: myip }
    - { path: ^/administrator, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

when accessing the administrator folder from another ip address it throws me to the login page and reports a redirect loop. Can someone explain me why don't i get an Access forbidden error instead of the redirect loop error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login is also secured with your ip requirement, so an access denied error you get redirect to the login page, but you get an acces denied too, redirect to the same page, access denied, redirect, and so on.

Remove the IP requirement from your login page.

Comment: From sf2 book: Also, be sure that the login page does not require any roles to be viewed
I was hoping ACCESS_DENIED would not redirect login -> login but looks like you're right. Is there a way to block the login form and allow just 1 (or more) ip that can access, because i want to allow access to the whole administrator/ folder just to 1 ip, plus login.